# URL приложения разворнутого с помощью docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Я новичек в docker, поэтому я не знаю как зайти на свое приложение.
У меня есть следующий dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./target/stm-eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-Dname=eureka", "-jar", "/app.jar" ]
```

И следующий docker-compose.yml файл:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  stm-eureka-server:
    image: stm-eureka-server-image:latest
    container_name: stm-eureka-server
    build: ./stm-eureka-server
    ports:
    - 8761:8761
    restart:
      unless-stopped
    networks:
    - stm-microservice

networks:
  stm-microservice:
```

Приложение успешно запустилось. Но как я выяснил определить урл немогу. Подскажите что к чему здесь пожалуйста.

UPDATE:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
0ac00433daba        stm-eureka-server-image:latest   "sh -c 'java $JAVA_O…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute           0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp   stm-eureka-server
```

Comment: Если вы правильно всё развернули, то должно быть на порте 8761, localhost:8761

Comment: @AndrewTarasenko This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect. Не могу почему то достучаться. В чем может быть проблема? Проапдейтил вопрос с тем что у меня на консоли.

Answer (score 0):

Решил ответить на собственный же вопрос. На Windows докер ложится не оч, по крайней мере для челвоека который с ним столкнулся впервые. Также нужно учитывать что есть разные способы поставить докер вэтой оси. Вобщем ответ заключается в том, что необходимо скопировать айпишник докер машины которая поднялась в системе и юзать его локально. localhost просто не будет работать в Windows, в отличии от linux систем.